# Android - listview - scroll programmatically to specific layout

Tags: android, listview, layout, smooth-scrolling

Here's my question :

I have a listview (with adapter) which contains multiple inflated layout for each row and I want to smooth scroll programmatically to a specific layout.

Exemple :

this is one listview row:

------------------

-                -

-     layout1    -

-                -

-     layout2    -

-     layout3    -

-     etc...     -

------------------

I know that in a Scrollview we can use getY() of the layout view but when i did this for my specific layout in listview it return me 0. But I can't use scrollview because I need to get SwipeRefreshLayout (Or we can get it in Scrollview ?)

I hope I was clear enough, if this is not the case, please tell me.

Comment: There is a method like scrollto(), use this method with smoothscroll() method

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering scroll by action like onClick.

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View row = listView.getChildAt(0);
        View layout = row.findViewById(R.id.layout_to_scroll_to);

       listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(rowPositionToScrollTo, layout.getTop());
    }
});
```

If you are triggering scroll on page load.  Add this in onCreate or onActivityCreated for Activity or Fragment, accordingly.

```
getListView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        listView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        View row = listView.getChildAt(0);
        View layout = row.findViewById(R.id.layout_to_scroll_to);

        listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(rowPositionToScrollTo, layout.getTop());
    }
});
```

Change `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` to `setSelectionFromTop` for no scroll animation.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it's that my problem, I don't want to scroll to a specific row but I want to scroll to a specific layout IN a row.
The smoothScrollBy method do the job but i can't get the position where to scroll (view.gety() return 0)

Comment: You should not use getY() but getTop(). getTop() returns the position of a child view relative to its parent view. If you get 0 it means it's at the top of its direct parent.

Comment: I tried getTop on layout3 (c.f my question) but it return me 0 too

Comment: Sorry my bad.  Missed that is actually a row.  I will update the answer if I find any.

Comment: Okay thanks but it's the same result, I try an other way to do that

Comment: Hmm, if you post your xml and code, I might be able to help to see what is going on.